When the sample size of positive event cases is small, how should the cases be sampled to save costs?
I have a question that has been troubling me for a long time, and I have consulted a lot of resources but have not found an accurate answer. My question is as follows: Assuming I have 10,000 patients, with only 100 deceased patients and 9,900 surviving patients, in order to reduce the cost of collecting medical records, I plan to randomly select 200 patients from the 9,900 surviving patients as the surviving group, and then combine them with the 100 deceased patients, resulting in a final sample of 300 patients. Is this sampling method acceptable? If so, what category does this sampling method belong to? Is it unequal proportion stratified sampling?

for rare positive events, I tried active learning in a similar setting but it was no better than random sampling for me... Or are you asking about the sample sizes? Then you need to do a power analysis with some assumptions first

It's a form of stratified sampling. The sampling ratio is usually the same between the groups or proportional to the whole, yours appears to be arbitrary.

Yes, I retained all patients in the death group (since the sample size is small and the samples are not easily obtainable) and conducted random sampling only from the survival group. The sampling proportion for the death group is 100%, while the sampling proportion for the survival group is only 100/9900 = 2.02%. Is this method appropriate?

This sounds like a [tag:case-control-study], have a look at that tag
